# I get an error when importing data into User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, active-admin-import

I am using devise gem for user session operations. I want to import data to the user model in the admin panel.

Ruby version: 2.4.1p111

Rails version: Rails 5.1.4

Admin panel gem: activeadmin

Admin panel import gem: active_admin_import

admin/user.rb

`ActiveAdmin.register User do
  active_admin_import validate: true,
                      template_object: ActiveAdminImport::Model.new(
                        hint: "Dosyanızda veriler belirtilen başlıklar altında olmalıdır: 'email', 'identity_no', 'password', 'password_confirmation'",
                        csv_headers: ['email', 'identity_no', 'password', 'password_confirmation']
                      )
  permit_params :email, :identity_no, :password, :password_confirmation
....
...
end`

models/user.rb

`class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :graduations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :works, dependent: :destroy
  validates :identity_no,  presence: true
...
...
end`

I received the error message:
`can't write unknown attribute password`

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason**

Devise creates `encrypted_password` database field, not `password` field and it overrides `password=` method to do the encryption then assigns encrypted one to `encrypted_password`.

`active_admin_import` does directly import, so it doesn't go through `password=` method, so the error occurs

**Solution**

Use `before_batch_import` to simulate encrypting process and assign encrypted password to `encrypted_password` field. No `password_confirmation` needed. Example:

```
active_admin_import validate: false,
  before_batch_import: proc { |import|
    import.csv_lines.length.times do |i|
      import.csv_lines[i][2] = User.new(password: import.csv_lines[i][2]).encrypted_password
    end
  },
  template_object: ActiveAdminImport::Model.new(
    csv_headers: ['email', 'identity_no', 'encrypted_password']
  ),
  timestamps: true
```